# Configure kotlin plugin update fail?

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, kotlin

I'm trying to update **kotlin** *plugin* through this window:

[image]

1-  I check for update.

2-  New version appear and i click install.

3-  After download and install i restart android studio.

I tried that about 5 times, and every time the *kotlin plugin* doesn't update.

Why I can't update it?

Am bit confused in the `plugins` i can find the final version, but when i open Configure kotlin plugin updates it's always check for updates and install it.

Comment: What’s the current version of the plugin you have installed?

Comment: @JKLy how i can know that ?

Comment: Preferences - Plugins, search `Kotlin`, the version number will be in the info pane.

Comment: @JKLy Version: 1.1.51-release-Studio3.0-1

Comment: That implies you already have the latest version installed?

Comment: Then why the dialog guide me to install new version?

Comment: It could be a bug with the update dialog - you could try uninstalling the plugin from the preferences page, and then reinstall to see if the issue persists.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Please try to restart your android-studio and I think this behaviour doesn't exist with android-studio 3.0 stable version.

Comment: Whenever in doubt, restart Android Studio.

Comment: well... it even exists in 3.2.1 Stable version, I'll try restart the studio and see what will happen

Answer (score 0):

I had a same issue on Android Studio 3.3 Beta 4 and solved.

Following:

- Remove ~/.AndroidStudioPreview3.3 directory.

Comment: bad answer (to delete the whole folder with your settings)

Answer (score 0):

Perform a Check for updates (Help -> Check for updates) in Android Studio. Maybe there is a pending update in Android Studio itself. When Android Studio is up to date, the Kotlin plugin should update flawlessly.